# format string for a GET request from browser in C socket Server -- need to parse GET request

Tags: c, http

I am making a small C TCP socket program for simple HTTP server and doing it in C. So in that I like to parse one request which is below, But Since I will loop though the request string came from browser so I need the exact HTTP request format with query string. Below is all I know plus I also know that in below request my server also gets `\t` for tab, `\r` for carret return and `\n` for next line But I dont know the order of `\t`, `r` and `\n` so anyone can please tell: what is the corrent http format string for below GET request. Thanks

```
GET /add?title=gedit&price=87 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/x
```

Comment: Did you check the links to related RFC specs in this [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: Parsing an HTTP request is generally a multiphase operation. First you must define what HTTP version you accept. Then you must parse separately the request line itself and the header lines. All should be terminated with a `\r\n` pair, but it is common to only use the `\n` and ignore any trailing blank character. Finally you only process the headers that matter for your use case and ignore the other ones. BTW the header block should be followed by an empty line. And as you have already been told, the reference is in the RFC pages...